# Can't find html tag when using Beautiful soup

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get more familiar with web scraping. I came across this website, https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe/ that gives an intro into web scraping using Beautiful Soup. Following the demonstration, I tried to scrape the value and name of the S&P stock index with the code they provided, but that wasn't working. I think some things have changed like the tag for price is no longer under h1 as the author wrote on the website. When I inspect the web page to view the html code, I can see all the tags used. I figured out that some of the html code isn't being scraped from the bloomberg website. I printed what the webscraper is collecting onto the console.

The code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
quote_page = "http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND"
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
print (soup)
name_box = soup.find("h1", attrs={"class": "price"})
name = name_box.text.strip() #get 'Nonetype object has no attribute text' here
print(name)
```

I was having troubles displaying what the code prints on stack, but basically some of the tags are not there. I'm wondering why this is and how to actually scrape the website. When I inspect the website, I can find the tag I am looking for which is:

```
<span class="priceText__1853e8a5">2,912.43</span>
```

But using the code I have, I can't seem to get this tag.

Comment: the tags aren't there because it's most lkely a dynamic site, meaning all that data is rendered by javascript. You won't get those tags by doing a simple request.

Comment: secondly, your code won't grab that if it is indeed in the html source because it's a `<span>` tag with the class attribute of `"priceText_1853e8a5"`. Your code is finding the `<h1>` tag with a class attribute of `"price"`

Comment: That tutorial is also outdated. So at the time, that code would have worked, but looks like that particular site has changed/updated since then. You can still pull it out of the html, but it's more complicated. My advice it try out a different website that is static.

Comment: okay thank you all